# loading in a MySQL table called "order" with RMySQL

Tags: r, rmysql

I'm currently trying to connect my R session to a MySQL server using the RMySQL package.
One of the tables on the server is called "order", I already searched  how you can import a table called order with MySQL (by putting it into ''), yet the syntax does not work for the RMySQL query.

when I run the following statement:

```
order_query = dbSendQuery(mydb,"SELECT * FROM 'order'")
```

It returns the following error:

> Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) :    could not run statement:
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''order'' at line 1

Anyone knows how to get around this in R?

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes in MySQL indicate string literals, and you should not be putting them around your table names.  Try the query without the quotes:

```
order_query = dbSendQuery(mydb,"SELECT * FROM `order`")
```

If you did, for some reason, need to escape your table name, then use backticks, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM `some table`    -- table name with a space (generally a bad thing)
```

**Edit:**

As @Ralf pointed out, in this case you do need backticks because `ORDER` is a MySQL keyword and you should not be using it to name your tables and columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot, without the quotes it doesn't work. But the backticks work perfectly! thanks a lot!

Comment: The backticks are necessary since `order` is a reserved word in SQL.